# How do you run a script when a kernel oops occurs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I would like to run a custom script when a kernel oops occurs. Is this possible, and if so how?

Comment: What are you trying to archieve?
You can probably play with kdump and somehow attach some other actions to it, but I think you may need to enable crash on oops kernel parameter which will make oops unrecoverable.

Comment: Anything you do after a kernel oops is going to be unreliable. The only meaningful thing you could want a script to do after a kernel oops is collect information which could potentially help identifying the root cause of the oops. If all you want to collect is the `dmesg` output, then there are better ways to achieve that such as serial console or netconsole.

Comment: There are two things I think I might want to do: send an email notification, and automatically reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I would answer that you could install `rsyslog` and run the script via the Shell Execute operator (`^program-to-execute;template`). However, it will probably not work, because the system will certainly be unresponsible after a kernel oops and will not run the custom script.

Because of that, I suggest you to run a script *in another server* when a kernel oops occurs. For example:

1. In the server that eventually produces kernel oops, forward messages to a "monitor" server using the [netconsole module](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Netconsole).

   ```
   # /etc/modprobe.d/netconsole.conf
   # This example assumes 10.0.0.1 as the "bad" server and 10.0.0.2 as the "monitor" server
   options netconsole netconsole=30514@10.0.0.1/eth0,30514@10.0.0.2/01:23:45:67:89:AB
   options netconsole oops_only=1


   # /etc/modules-load.d/netconsole.conf
   # Tells 'systemd-modules-load' to load 'netconsole' automatically at boot
   netconsole
   ```
2. In the monitor server (the one which receives kernel oops), run the custom script via `rsyslog`.

   ```
   # /etc/rsyslog.d/kernel-oops-handler.conf

   module(load="imudp")

   input(type="imudp" 
       port="30514"
       ruleset="KernelOopsRuleSet")

   # This aims to supply the IP address of the "bad" server in command line
   template(name="KernelOopsArgs"
       type="string"
       string="%fromhost-ip%")

   ruleset(name="KernelOopsRuleSet") {
       # This assumes that the '--[ cut here ]--' string is a kernel oops evidence
       if ($msg contains "------------[ cut here ]------------") then {
           kern.crit ^/path/to/custom/script.sh;KernelOopsArgs
       }
   }
   ```
3. The custom script may restart the machine via the out-of-band management interface (iDRAC on Dell servers):

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # /path/to/custom/script.sh
   # A successful SSH to the host indicates the server is responsible
   sleep 3
   server="${1}"
   if ! ssh -n -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=none "${server}" true; then
       # Let me suppose 10.100.0.1 is the iDRAC IP address of a server whose IP is 10.0.0.1
       idrac="`echo \"${server}\" | sed 's/^10\.0\./10.100./'`"
       # Trigger a forced reboot using 'ipmitool'
       ipmitool -H "${idrac}" -U root -P root chassis power reset
       # Notify administrators
       mail -s "Server '${server}' was restarted!" sysadmins@example.com < /dev/null
   fi
   ```